# Connecting the Database

Tags: mysql, eclipse, maven, spring-mvc, workbench

How do I get maven project to connect with mysql database in workbench?

What I want to do is to create a web app CRUD project that has read & write data to a database on MySql Workbench.

Comment: Do you want to connect the database to your program that you write in Eclipse, or do you want to connect the database to Eclipse so that you can use the DB editing/design tools of Eclipse ?

Comment: I want to connect the database to Eclipse so that Ican use the DB editing/design tools of Eclipse

Answer (score 0):

There ya go:

- http://www.eclipse.org/datatools/ will connect you to an SQL database and help you explore and query it
- http://www.eclipse.org/webtools/dali/gettingstarted.php will help you with JPA entities and the database (either creating the entities from the database or the database from the entities).
- http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.4/solutions/restful_jpa.htm will show you how to expose your JPA entities as REST endpoints so that a frontend can access them.